# How to show only top item in ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, expander

I have list of items shown vertically and right beneath it I have some kind of expander(button with arrow/toggle button/...). What I want to do is when the expander is collapsed only one item is shown. When the expander is expanded all items are shown.

What I thought is:

1. Remove/Add items to `ObservableCollection` that is bound to `ListView` and thus showing only one or all items.
2. Use `ScrollViewer` that will somehow show only first item and when the expander is expanded to change the height of `ScrollViewer`.
3. Other way..

Comment: At first sight, I will bind my ListView to `myCollection.Take(1)` when the expander is expanded, or to `myCollection` if not.

Comment: It's precisely what I'm doing right now (option #1). I though maybe there are some controls that know how to show single or more items